# How to maintain dependencies located at personal servers with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

We are using android studio for android development.
We are using lot of java libraries in our android development.To keep jar files at one place we kept them on our server.
So here is the scenario
We are using **java1.jar,java2.jar,java3.jar,java4.jar** all of then located on remote server in one folder.
So how to gradle build script which will download all the four jars for us and ads references to our android project.
Can anyone please guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a private Maven or Ivy repo.

The two biggest for Maven are [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) and [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview).